# Why my time data is not showing after scraping?

Tags: html, node.js

I am using node js for web scraping. Whenever I try to get the date for a match it is not showing me any date. Even when I try to get the html of fixture it is not showing me any html.

```
const fixture = $('.fixtures');
const date = fixture.find('.date long').text(); 
console.log(fixture.html());
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Could you give a sample of the html you are scraping?

Comment: I am trying to scrap the EPL fixture.


const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/fixtures';

axios.get(url)
  .then(response => {
    const $ = cheerio.load (response.data);

    const fixture = $('.fixtures');
    //const time = fixture.find('.shortname').text();
    fixture.each(function(){
      const date = fixture.find('.date long').text();
      console.log(date);
    });    
  });

sorry for my bad reply as I am new to stack overflow

Comment: You can edit your question. But to help we need a sample of de HTML you are scraping. You gave code, we need the content.